# How to fix hair particle shading/topology issue?

Tags: hair

There is no way to describe the issue, that's why I'm just going to show the rendered image:

[image]

Those are 4 planes with no modifiers, the same dimensions, the same particles, and the same material. The only difference is the topology. All planes are hidden - only the hair is visible.

- Number 1 is a simple plane
- Number 2 is a plane with loop cuts (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
- Number 3 is extruded (I started with a small plane and made it bigger with extrusions)
- Number 4 is the same as Num.3 but the cuts are made with "*Knife projection*"

[image]

---

Numbers 1 and 2 are good, the issues are in 3 and 4

All faces have the same normals. I tied recalculating the normals, I also tried flipping them - nothing worked.

Just in case anyone asks - I'm making a big project and the model with the hair is very complex (I used extrusions, knife projections, and more) that's why I need to fix it without retopologizing the whole mesh. Because the project file is big I made this .blend file with the planes where I recreated the same issue.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand it, but what I think is going on is that the hairs are set to have "children" and blender is applying a slight rotation to the kink direction of the child hairs via the "Amplitude" value of the kink curl. Setting the value to 0 removes the strange patterning, as does changing the kink type to "nothing", "radial" and "spiral". The other options still show artifacts. I still can't fully explain it, but at least this should make it "go away", if that's what you're after.

[image: Kink]

Comment: Thank you very much. But there is no curl now